# MongoDB countDocuments vs exists vs find vs findOne, which is the fastest way to check if a doc exists?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am facing different opinions at different blogs and answers!

Please forgive me in advance if it seems to be stupid to ask but your help will be appreciated!

This issue seems still unclear to me, there are too many ways to check if a document exists but i am not sure which may be the fastest way possible after so many updates mongodb has released till today in 2020.

Comment: this is something you can easily measure yourself, no?

Comment: If you are not interested in sharing your views, please don't but atleast let others have a look! @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 1):

`find({ <PREDICATE> }).limit(1)` and `findOne({ <PREDICATE> })` will result in same amount of time. As the query optimiser will evaluate it the same way.

Fastest queries in MongoDB are covered queries. That is the queries covered by an index and there's no FETCH stage. If you simply want to check the existence of the document. This will be the fastest query:

```
db.users.find({_id : 10021 )}, {_id: 1})
```

Above query relies on the _id index (which will always be there) and projecting only `_id` so it doesn't go to disk at all.

`count` **without predicate** is not always accurate, as it relies on metadata.

If you want exact count, you should do it in an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: `count()` without "Predicate" is not accurate as it returns the results based of metadata. Secondly `count()` is equivalent to the `db.collection.find(query).count() construct.`

 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/